# Is there a simple way of improving the precision of pgfmath for trig functions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I wanted to build a table of trig values using `pgfmath`.  However, the precision is a bit off.  Is there a way to improve this within `TikZ`?

This is related to a similar question I just posted: [Is there a way to pad zeros to the end of a rounded number with Expl3?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166977/22413)

Here's my current working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fixedpointarithmetic}

\def\mynum{0}
\def\myvoffset{0pt}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

Using \texttt{TikZ}

\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=4,verbatim]

  \coordinate(UL) at (0,0);

  \node at (UL) {Degrees};
  \node[anchor=west] at ($(UL.west)+(1cm,0)$) {$\sin$};
  \node[anchor=west] at ($(UL.west)+(2.75cm,0)$) {$\cos$};
  \node[anchor=west] at ($(UL.west)+(4.50cm,0)$) {$\tan$};

  \foreach \myn in {1,2,3,...,45}
  {
    \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\myn-1,5))}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0\relax
      \xdef\myvoffset{\dimexpr\myvoffset+1.350\baselineskip}%%
    \else
      \xdef\myvoffset{\dimexpr\myvoffset+1.00\baselineskip}%%
    \fi

    \coordinate (DEG/\myn)   at ($(UL.west)-(0,\myvoffset)$);
    \coordinate (DEG/S/\myn) at ($(DEG/\myn)+(1cm,0)$);
    \coordinate (DEG/C/\myn) at ($(DEG/S/\myn)+(1.75cm,0)$);
    \coordinate (DEG/T/\myn) at ($(DEG/C/\myn)+(1.75cm,0)$);

    \node[anchor=east] at (DEG/\myn) {$\myn^\circ$};
    \pgfmathparse{sin(\myn)} \node[anchor=west] at (DEG/S/\myn) {\texttt{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}};
    \pgfmathparse{cos(\myn)} \node[anchor=west] at (DEG/C/\myn) {\texttt{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}};
    \pgfmathparse{tan(\myn)} \node[anchor=west] at (DEG/T/\myn) {\texttt{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}};

  }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know with `pgfmath`; with `expl3` you can compile your table like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array,siunitx}

\sisetup{
  add-decimal-zero,
  round-precision=5,
  round-mode=places,
  round-integer-to-decimal,
  group-digits=false,
  detect-all,
}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\trigtable}{ }
 {
  \__aellett_do_trig:
  \begin{tabular}{r *{3}{ >{\ttfamily}r }}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\sin$}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\cos$}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\tan$}
  \\
  \tl_use:N \l__aellett_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }

\tl_new:N \l__aellett_body_tl

\cs_new:Npn \aellett_compute:nn #1 #2
 {
  \num { \fp_to_decimal:n { \fp_eval:n { round ( #1(#2) , 5 ) } } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__aellett_do_trig:
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__aellett_body_tl
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { 89 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__aellett_body_tl { $##1^\circ$ & }
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l__aellett_body_tl
     { 
      \aellett_compute:nn { sind } { ##1 } &
      \aellett_compute:nn { cosd } { ##1 } &
      \aellett_compute:nn { tand } { ##1 } 
     }
    \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { ##1 } { 5 } == 0 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__aellett_body_tl { \\[1ex] }
     }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__aellett_body_tl { \\ }
     }
   }
  % 90 degrees
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l__aellett_body_tl
   {
    $90^\circ$ &
    \aellett_compute:nn { sind } { 90 } &
    \aellett_compute:nn { cosd } { 90 } &
    --- 
   }

 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\tiny
\trigtable

\end{document}
```

Here's the start:

[image: start]

And here's the end, just to show what happens at 89 degrees:

[image: end]

I used five digits for comparison with the value `bc` returns for the tangent of 89 degrees:

> 57.28996163075942465214

Comment: You could also substitute `$##1^\circ$` with `\ang{##1}` to use `siunitx`.

Comment: @Manuel You're right; but I almost never use angles in degree, so I resorted to the old school method. ;-)

Comment: This is for high school students' first exposure to trigonometry.  They won't learn about radians until much later.

Comment: @A.Ellett Why? The sooner they get away with degrees, the better.

Comment: Unlike university teaching, I don't have much say about the how, what, or when of math content.  The benefit of degrees though is that the students are already familiar with them and so they can focus on what is new, the trig functions.

Answer (score 3):

Extend your options with `fixed zerofill`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fixedpointarithmetic}
\def\mynum{0}
\def\myvoffset{0pt}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
%Using \texttt{TikZ}
\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=4,verbatim, fixed zerofill]
  \coordinate(UL) at (0,0);
  \node at (UL) {Degrees};
  \node[anchor=west] at ($(UL.west)+(1cm,0)$) {$\sin$};
  \node[anchor=west] at ($(UL.west)+(2.75cm,0)$) {$\cos$};
  \node[anchor=west] at ($(UL.west)+(4.50cm,0)$) {$\tan$};
  \foreach \myn in {1,2,3,...,45}
  {
    \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\myn-1,5))}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0\relax
      \xdef\myvoffset{\dimexpr\myvoffset+1.350\baselineskip}%%
    \else
      \xdef\myvoffset{\dimexpr\myvoffset+1.00\baselineskip}%%
    \fi
    \coordinate (DEG/\myn)   at ($(UL.west)-(0,\myvoffset)$);
    \coordinate (DEG/S/\myn) at ($(DEG/\myn)+(1cm,0)$);
    \coordinate (DEG/C/\myn) at ($(DEG/S/\myn)+(1.75cm,0)$);
    \coordinate (DEG/T/\myn) at ($(DEG/C/\myn)+(1.75cm,0)$);
    \node[anchor=east] at (DEG/\myn) {$\myn^\circ$};
    \pgfmathparse{sin(\myn)} \node[anchor=west] at (DEG/S/\myn) {\texttt{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}};
    \pgfmathparse{cos(\myn)} \node[anchor=west] at (DEG/C/\myn) {\texttt{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}};
    \pgfmathparse{tan(\myn)} \node[anchor=west] at (DEG/T/\myn) {\texttt{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 3):

With the standard TeX arithmetic, precision is very limited.If you need more accurate results, you may need to use some external program or any extension of TeX, such as luatex.

Using my package [calculator](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/calculator) I get results similar to what you get with Tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{angle}
\newcommand{\trigfunctions}[1]{%
    #1^{\mathrm{o}} &
    \DEGREESSIN{#1}{\sine}
    \ROUND[4]{\sine}{\sine}
    \sine & 
    \DEGREESCOS{#1}{\cosine}
    \ROUND[4]{\cosine}{\cosine}
    \cosine  & 
    \DEGREESTAN{#1}{\tangent}
    \ROUND[4]{\tangent}{\tangent}
    \tangent& 
    \DEGREESCOT{#1}{\cotangent}
    \ROUND[4]{\cotangent}{\cotangent}
    \cotangent \\}

\small
\[
\begin{array}{*{5}{r}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\alpha} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\sin\alpha} & 
                             \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cos \alpha} & 
                             \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tan\alpha} & 
                             \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cot\alpha} \\
\whiledo{\value{angle}<45}{\stepcounter{angle}\trigfunctions{\theangle}}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: trig table]